# dbt two argument ref

Tags: dbt

How do I refer to relative path from `view1` to `view2` using `ref('package_name', 'model_name')` ?

```
/root_folder
   / project1
     /models
       view1.sql
     dbt_project.yml

   / project2
     /models
       view2.sql
     dbt_project.yml
```

There is no code example in [the documentation](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/ref/#advanced-ref-usage).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To try and answer the question with a little more focus on your comment:

> I have one folder for each dataset I have on bigquery. Can I write models for several datasets in one single folder?

Yes you can!

Quick note on terms from the dbt docs ["BigQuery configurations"](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/bigquery-configs) in case you are not using bigquery.

> - schema is interchangeable with the BigQuery concept dataset
> - database is interchangeable with the BigQuery concept of project

Here is how this works for me:

```
project-dir
     | analysis
     | data
     | macros
     | models
         |> sources
              - dataset1.yml
              - dataset2.yml
     | seed
     | dbt_project.yml
     | packages.yml
```

Where the contents of a dataset.yml is:

```
version: 2

sources:
  - name: fivetran_log
    database: my-bigquery-project-id
    loader: fivetran
    
    tables:
      - name: account
      - name: log
      - name: user
```

No references are required within the dbt_project.yml to utilize these sources immediately. Instead, you can reference this directly from models like:

```
select * 
from {{ source('fivetran_log', 'user') }}
```

That should allow you to have multiple dataset sources, but one single dbt project directory for all your views.

However, if the datasets you are referencing are within different bigquery regions or different billing projects, I believe you will run into some errors.

---

Appendix of related questions / resources across the dbt-verse:

- [Should I have an organisation wide project (a monorepo) or should each work flow have their own?](https://discourse.getdbt.com/t/should-i-have-an-organisation-wide-project-a-monorepo-or-should-each-work-flow-have-their-own/666/2)
- [Building dbt models to be compatible with multiple data warehouses](https://discourse.getdbt.com/t/building-dbt-models-to-be-compatible-with-multiple-data-warehouses/402)

Answer (score 5):

The only way for `project2` to know about models in `project1` is if `project2` included `project1` as a package in its `packages.yml` file. Then you could refer to `view1` as `ref('project1', 'view1')` in `project2`.

You'll have to check the syntax here, but you could include `project1` in `project2` in `packages.yml` like so:

in `project2\packages.yml`:

```yaml
packages:
    - local: ../project1
```

Needless to say, you'd save yourself a lot of headaches by simply not splitting projects. In most cases you shouldn't need to do that and simple folderization does most of what you might need.

Comment: I have one folder for each dataset I have on bigquery. Can I write models for several datasets in one single folder?

Comment: I tried but it looks like your technique overrides the `target.schema` variable from project1 which then causes a runtime error.

Comment: I think you want to take a look at custom schemas to solve the larger issue of organizing models and targets. https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/using-custom-schemas/

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve the multi dataset project.